# CRNN tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode. What is log probability?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, ocr

Based on [the documentation](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/keras/backend/ctc_decode), the function `tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode` is supposed to return a `Tuple`. Its first field contains the best path (let's assume we use greedy search), whereas the second one contains its `log probability`.

Is this probability actually the accuracy of the prediction?

If not how am I supposed to calculate it?

I've tried on some test images and this was my output:

```
True value: test0, prediction: test0, acc: 1.841524362564087
True value: test1, prediction: test1, acc: 0.9661365151405334
True value: test2, prediction: test2, acc: 1.0634151697158813
True value: test3, prediction: test3, acc: 2.471940755844116
True value: test4, prediction: test4, acc: 1.4866207838058472
True value: test5, prediction: test5, acc: 0.7630811333656311
True value: test6, prediction: test6, acc: 0.35642576217651367
True value: test7, prediction: test7, acc: 1.5693446397781372
True value: test8, prediction: test8, acc: 0.9700028896331787
True value: test9, prediction: test9, acc: 1.4783780574798584
```

During the training part, the final CTC loss was around 0.1 and the prediction is always correct. However what I think it's the probability seems not to be what I expect. They looks like completely random numbers, even grater than 1 or 2! What am I doing wrong?